# this.setState to child object

Tags: reactjs

I want to update the state for a user form but `this.state.data` only returns the last input changed

```
class User extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            data: ''
        }
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target
        const value = (target.type === 'checkbox') ? target.checked : target.value
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({ data: {
            [name]: value
        }})

        console.log(this.state.data)

    }
}

<input type="text" name="text1" value={this.state.data.text1} onChange={(event) => this.handleInputChange(event)} />
<input type="text" name="text2" value={this.state.data.text2} onChange={(event) => this.handleInputChange(event)} />
```

it works fine if I do

```
this.setState({ [name]: value })
```

I'm making an http request to a service and I want to send only `this.state.data` and not the entire `this.state` because most of the things are useless for that service. I only need the form data. thank you

Comment: If `this.setState({ [name]: value })` is working, what's the issue exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects and arrays behave differently than primitive types (int, float, string) they are pointers in memory, in order to change the value of and object you need to create a copy of the object using spread operator and then change the value and pass the entire new object to the state like this:

```
let data = {...this.state.data} //this is the spread operator that copies the data
const target = event.target
const value = (target.type === 'checkbox') ? target.checked : target.value
const name = target.name
data[name] = value
this.setState({data: data})
```

that should work

when working with objects and arrays you need to be careful, the problem you had is that you were setting two different pointers to objects in memory... if you are a beginner is hard to get your head around but keep practicing and try to learn pointers in C